# Extract links for certain section only from blogspot using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to extract links for certain section only from Blogspot. But the output shows the codes extract all the link inside the page.

Here is the codes:

```
import urlparse
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/"

urls = [url]
visited = [url]

while len(urls) >0:
      try:
          htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
      except:
          print urls[0]

      soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

      urls.pop(0)
      print len (urls)

      for tags in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': "post-title entry-title"}):
           for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
                tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url,tag['href'])
                if url in tag['href'] and tag['href'] not in visited:
                    urls.append(tag['href'])
                    visited.append(tag['href'])

print visited
```

Here is the html codes for section that I want to extract:

```
<h3 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="name">
<a href="http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2011/02/pre-wedding-vintage.html">Pre-wedding * Vintage*</a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need to use `BeautifulSoup` I think it would be easier to do something like this:

```
import feedparser

url = feedparser.parse('http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss')
for x in url.entries:
    print str(x.link)
```

**Output:**

```
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2011/03/my-vintage-pre-wedding.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2011/02/pre-wedding-vintage.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/tissue-paper-flower-crepe-paper.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/menguap-menurut-islam.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/weddings-idea.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/kawin.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/11/vitamin-c-collagen.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/11/port-dickson.html
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/11/ellys-world.html
```

[feedparser](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) can parse the RSS feed of the blogspot page and can return the data you want, in this case the `href` for the post titles.

Comment: btw I have question, why it only extracts until 25 links?

Comment: that's the maximum links the RSS feed returns

Comment: that's mean i cannot extract more than it?

Answer (score 0):

you need add .get to the object:

print Objecta.get('href')

Example from http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thank you. But it still extracts all the link inside the blogspot page. I only need href from <h3 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="name">.